# Python: I want to make a screenshot script that consecutively names files

Tags: python, file, jpeg

So far, I have written a script to take screenshots and save them. But I want the files to be named "snap", followed by a number (e.g. snap1.jpg, snap2.jpg, snap3.jpg). The plan is to make a ew picture every time the script executes. Here is the current script:

```
import ImageGrab
img = ImageGrab.grab()
img.save('snap1.jpg','JPEG')
```

Comment: Do you want this to be a continuous loop, or do you want to just create a file with the next open number after "snap" every time you run it?

Comment: I want it to be every time I run it.

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
import sys

basename = sys.argv[1]

# for each file in the current directory, check if its name starts with basename
# if it does, split on basename this will yield ['', N] where N is the number in the filename
# call int on the number since it is currently a string
numbers = [int(f.split(basename)[1]) for f in os.listdir('.') if f.startswith(basename)]
last_number = max(numbers) # I broke this up so it was easier to see
new_name = "%s%03d.jpg" % (basename, last_number + 1)
print new_name
```

Notes.

- uses '.' aka current dir as the location, update as needed.
- the new_name is written like snap003.jpg. Again, adjust as needed. The zeroes help a file listing line up

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this into a loop, and each time you take a screenshot increment a counter.

```
i = 1
while (condition):
    ImageGrab.grab()
    img.save('snap'+str(i)+'.jpg','JPEG')
```

However, since you want to simply run the application and have it know what to name it, you could always create another file to hold the number you're on. Let's say you call it `screen.txt` and put nothing but a zero in this file.
Now modify your code to be something like:

```
f = open('screen.txt')
i = int(f.read())
f.close()
print ('snap'+str(i)+'.jpg')
f = open('screen.txt', 'w')
i+=1
f.write(str(i))
```

You'll want to replace that print statement with your `img.save` statement. This should work and is pretty darn easy to understand.

Comment: Python doesn't do concatenation that way - your `'snap' + i + '.jpg'` should be something like `'snap%i.jpg' % i`.

Comment: I changed it to make `i` into a string, so that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The generation of the filename could be simple

```
i = 1 # somewhere above the grabbing

filename = 'snap%i.jpg' % i
i += 1
img.save(filename, 'JPEG')
```

`itertools` provides a nice counter generator, so you can do

```
import itertools
filecounter = itertools.count(1)

filename = 'snap%i.jpg' % filecounter.next()
```

The advantage of having the counter is that you can send it around to other functions without bothering to transfer state back. You might also want to construct a function to figure out the next filename based on what files already exist, but that's a little more involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you're saving to the same directory every time you run the script, then you can check the directory for files named /snap[0-9]+.jpeg/ (That is, files named snap, followed by a number, followed by ".jpg") and name your new file the next available file name. So something like this should work:

```
import os
import ImageGrab
import re

snapPattern = re.compile('snap([0-9]+)\.jpeg')

usedNumbers = []
fileList = os.listdir('.')
for filename in fileList:
    m = snapPattern.match(filename)
    if( m ):
        usedNumbers.append( m.group(1) )
usedNumbers.sort()
i = 0
while usedNumbers.count( str(i) ):
    i++
img = ImageGrab.grab()
img.save('snap'+str(i)+'.jpg','JPEG')
```

I apologize in advance if I screwed this up, I'm not extremely proficient with Python.